# Why isn't the Skype Chrome extension showing up on my home PC?

Tags: google-chrome, skype, google-chrome-extensions

I have Chrome installed at both home and work and I'm syncing:

- Bookmarks
- Extensions
- Preferences

between the two.

Changes I make to bookmarks and preferences on one are showing up (as expected) on the other.

However, the Skype extension is not installed on my home PC while it is on my work PC. I have Skype installed on both machines too. And when Skype updated to the latest version it installed the Firefox extension and the IE toolbar.

What do I have to do to get the extension on my home PC?

Oops - forgot to add - Home PC is Windows XP, work PC is Windows 7 (not that it should really make a difference).

Comment: Have you tried syncing **Apps**? Also, are both browsers synced up to date?

Comment: @Thiago - yes both browsers are up to date. I hadn't thought of apps as Skype calls itself an extension.

Comment: I have everything checked on my syncing preferences except for Bookmarks, and it syncs all my extensions and **apps** I guess. Just a thought. See if that helps.

Comment: @Thiago - tried that, didn't work. I'm really thinking that installing it directly is the only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the extension is not available on the Chrome Web store, then it will not be synced. I've seen this happen to several extensions which are in private beta (Xobni), or are not available in Chrome Webstore ( eg: user scripts) or those installed from respective websites ( an extension that I created, LastPass).

The only solution is as [Peter Maxwell mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/301333/why-isnt-the-skype-chrome-extension-showing-up-on-my-home-pc/303027#303027), to install them manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can try installing it manually from here http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/clickandcall/.

Comment: I beginning to think that's the only solution.